# How can I make a sticky menu, but not for the navbar at top, it's for something above footer?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to make some logo above footer and when I scroll down to 0, I see footer is below that logo. when I scroll up I want to see that logo is fixed on top of everything and footer is hidden.

Who can tell me how to do that?

Comment: What did you try? Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code?

Comment: post the site at least and we can inspect it

Answer (score 0):

I think this code below is what you're trying to accomplish.

HTML:

```
<header> </header>



<div id="container">  

  <img src="http://www-archive.mozilla.org/foundation/identity-guidelines/firefox-128.png" height=150px width=150px />

</div>


<div id="footer"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
width: 100%;
background-color: #686868;
height:150px;
}

#container {
width: 60%;
height:500px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-left:200px;
padding: 0 2em 2em 2em;
position: relative;
margin-bottom:100px;
z-index:10;
}

#container img {
margin-top:0px;
position:fixed;
}


#footer {
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
padding: 0 2em 2em 2em;
position: relative;
height:30px;
}
```

jFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LynchJustRules/eZj9W/